# SQlite database in iOS app is encrypted after download

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

I want to create a simple iOS app. This app downloads a simple SQlite database from URL.
But when the database is downloaded and stored in Documents folder, I can't open it by some SQLite manager, because it says it's encrypted despite the original database is not.

Also the code for reading this database is not working and I think is because the database is encrypted in Documents folder. Here is what I got so far.

```
-(void) downloadDatabase {


    NSString *stringURL = @"https://www.dropbox.com/s/cq8y6x29e6ku65r/database.sqlite";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    if ( urlData != nil )
    {
        NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"database.sqlite"];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        NSLog(@"Stahujem databazu do: %@", filePath);
    }
}
```

This is how I download the database in app.

```
// Get the documents directory
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = dirPaths[0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc]
                    initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                     @"database.sqlite"]];

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT * FROM CHAMPIONS";

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(myDatabase, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            [list removeAllObjects];
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {

                NSString *text = [[NSString alloc]
                                  initWithUTF8String:
                                  (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(
                                                                     statement, 1)];

                [list addObject:text];
                statusOfGettingDataFromDB = @"Found!";
                NSLog(@"count: %d", [list count]);
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(myDatabase);
    }
```

And with this code I'm trying to get some data from database. But after `sqlite3_prepare_v2` it jumps right at the end.

Can You please give me some info what I've done wrong? And advice me how to fix this? 
I woud be really grateful. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are downloading is currently returning an HTML page rather than the SQLite file.

Hence the `.sqlite` file you write to documents directory is not valid. Your code is working correct if you modify the URL

Try with this URL instead, this is the actual URL which is hit on click of Download button on the Dropbox page.

```
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/cq8y6x29e6ku65r/database.sqlite?token_hash=AAH9fdYQzZ6zj8CzhKVBGMi4LcaCRCHNKIlw88wLLskRWQ&dl=1
```

I tried your code and printed the `list` array fetched from the sqlite db and this the result I get in log,

```
(
 Ahri,
 Aatrox
 )
```

Hope that helps!